# Magento : MySQL server crash when “Copying to tmp table” process runs

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database-connection, magento-1.6

We have around 8k products in our Magento store. The following query starts every 5 minutes and does not seem end. I have checked process chart and found this query running many times. When MySQL reaches to its allowed connection (200 Concurrent Connections are allowed), it is crashed. This is happening in every hour and we have to restart the MySQL server.

I googled and didn't get any solution.

```
SELECT`e`.* , IF( at_status.value_id >0, at_status.value, at_status_default.value )AS`status` , IF( at_visibility.value_id >0, at_visibility.value, at_visibility_default.value )AS`visibility` ,`at_price`.`value`AS`price` ,`stock`.`qty` ,`stock`.`is_in_stock` ,`stock`.`manage_stock` ,`stock`.`use_config_manage_stock` ,`url`.`request_path` ,`categories`.* , GROUP_CONCAT( categories_index.category_id )AS`categories_ids` ,`price_index`.`min_price` ,`price_index`.`max_price` ,`price_index`.`tier_price` ,`price_index`.`final_price` 
FROM`catalog_product_entity`AS`e` 
INNERJOIN`catalog_product_website`AS`product_website`ON product_website.product_id = e.entity_id
AND product_website.website_id =\'2\'
INNERJOIN`catalog_product_entity_int`AS`at_status_default`ON (`at_status_default`.`entity_id`=`e`.`entity_id`) 
AND (
 `at_status_default`.`attribute_id`=\'87\'
)
AND`at_status_default`.`store_id`=0
LEFTJOIN`catalog_product_entity_int`AS`at_status`ON (`at_status`.`entity_id`=`e`.`entity_id`) 
AND (
 `at_status`.`attribute_id`=\'87\'
)
AND (
 `at_status`.`store_id`=2
)
INNERJOIN`catalog_product_entity_int`AS`at_visibility_default`ON (`at_visibility_default`.`entity_id`=`e`.`entity_id`) 
AND (
 `at_visibility_default`.`attribute_id`=\'93\'
)
AND`at_visibility_default`.`store_id`=0
LEFTJOIN`catalog_product_entity_int`AS`at_visibility`ON (`at_visibility`.`entity_id`=`e`.`entity_id`) 
AND (
 `at_visibility`.`attribute_id`=\'93\'
)
AND (
 `at_visibility`.`store_id`=2
)
INNERJOIN`catalog_product_entity_decimal`AS`at_price`ON (`at_price`.`entity_id`=`e`.`entity_id`) 
AND (
 `at_price`.`attribute_id`=\'67\'
)
AND (
 `at_price`.`store_id`=0
)
LEFTJOIN`cataloginventory_stock_item`AS`stock`ON stock.product_id = e.entity_id
LEFTJOIN`core_url_rewrite`AS`url`ON url.product_id = e.entity_id
AND url.category_id ISNULL 
AND is_system =1
AND ISNULL( options ) 
AND url.store_id =2
LEFTJOIN`catalog_category_product`AS`categories`ON categories.product_id = e.entity_id
INNERJOIN`catalog_category_product_index`AS`categories_index`ON categories_index.category_id = categories.category_id
AND categories_index.product_id = categories.product_id
AND categories_index.store_id =2
AND categories_index.category_id
IN ( 3, 298, 299, 300, 301, 302, 306, 462, 463, 464, 465, 466, 467, 468, 469, 470, 303, 434, 435, 436, 441, 442, 443, 444, 445, 446, 304, 305, 480, 481, 482, 307, 309, 310, 311, 474, 313, 447, 448, 449, 418, 312, 419, 479, 314, 405, 406, 407, 408, 409, 315, 428, 438, 316, 415, 416, 417, 317, 402, 403, 404, 384, 385, 387, 388, 389, 390, 391, 430, 437, 439, 440, 308, 378, 379, 380, 381, 382, 458, 459, 383, 392, 393, 394, 395, 396, 397, 398, 399, 400, 401, 450, 451, 497, 452, 454, 455, 456, 457, 460, 461, 318, 319, 420, 421, 422, 423, 320, 424, 425, 426, 427, 321, 322, 323, 364, 365, 366, 367, 473, 487, 488, 489, 490, 491, 492, 483, 484, 485, 486, 324, 325, 369, 370, 326, 453, 327, 328, 371, 372, 329, 376, 377, 330, 373, 374, 331, 332, 333, 334, 471, 335, 375, 337, 338, 336, 431, 432, 433, 339, 340, 341, 496, 342, 343, 344, 345, 346, 347, 348, 493, 495, 498, 499, 500, 502, 503, 349, 350, 351, 494, 501, 352, 353, 354, 355, 356, 357, 358, 359, 360, 361, 362, 363, 410, 411, 412, 413, 414, 368, 475, 477, 478) 
LEFTJOIN`catalog_product_index_price`AS`price_index`ON price_index.entity_id = e.entity_id
AND customer_group_id =0
AND price_index.website_id =2
WHERE (
IF( at_status.value_id >0, at_status.value, at_status_default.value )=\'1\'
)
AND (
 `e`.`type_id` 
IN (
 \'simple\',\'configurable\',\'bundle\',\'grouped\',\'virtual\',\'downloadable\'
))
AND (
IF( at_visibility.value_id >0, at_visibility.value, at_visibility_default.value ) 
IN (
 \'2\',\'3\',\'4\'
))
AND (
at_price.value >\'0\'
)
AND (
(
is_in_stock !=\'0\'
OR (
manage_stock !=\'1\'
AND use_config_manage_stock !=\'1\'
)
OR (
use_config_manage_stock !=\'0\'
AND 1=0
AND is_in_stock =0
)))
GROUPBY`e`.`entity_id` , `e`.`entity_id` 
LIMIT 1500
```

Comment: 8k products are not many for magento. However have you checked if the cache is enable in your CMS? It's made to avoid this kind of issues. Check it out and let me know Tsimtsum.

Comment: @medina Yes, Cache is enabled.

Comment: Tsimtsum, how about the indexes in System > Index Management?

Comment: All indexes are fine.